# Edit value inside PLIST in Linux

Tags: xml, perl, bash, awk, plist

I have an XML [Plist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plist), and I need a bash script to edit the integer value of a key in the case that that key exists, or else create the key and integer value if it does not. This is a Linux machine, so Mac OS X' `defaults` command is not available.

That is, the final Plist would look like:

```
<dict>
    …
    <key>myKey</key>
    <integer>54</integer>
    …
</dict>
```

whether the key `myKey` already existed in the original Plist or not, and where the integer value `54` is provided by a variable.

In Mac OS X I would do it like this:

```
defaults write ./myPlist myKey -int $(echo $myKey_value)
```

but like I said, no `defaults` command in Linux. I tried with `sed`, but apparently it can only match single lines. Maybe `awk` or `perl` would do, but I know almost nothing of either.

Answer (score 3):

[Data::Plist::XMLWriter](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aPlist%3a%3aXMLWriter)

Comment: I'd rather not have to install anything, hence why I was trying with sed and thought that maybe awk or perl were also good for the job.

Comment: @elmimmo: AWK and `sed` are not up to the job. The link in the answer is for a Perl module.

Comment: I understand how XMLWriter is a specialized tool for the job. Yet, this is the only single XML operation that the script needs to do, and no other of similar nature is needed on this computer either. Hence, i was thinking of a simpler approach:

if line containing <key>myKey</key> exists; then delete that line and the following; add line <key>myKey</key>; add following line <integer>${myKey_value}</integer> eof

Are you sure awk cannot do that? Mmph… I'd like this to be as portable as possible, hence installing perl modules or other stuff is not nice.

Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It depends on how long & deep your plists are going to be. It'd be trivial to pick out a single `<key>asdf</key>` entry using awk/sed/ack/grep. If you anticipate having to deal with more than that, use the XMLWriter. Apple has a DTD here: http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd